# AWK - How to extract matches including part of filename from multiple files

Tags: grep, sed, awk

i have 1000 files with filename like this :

**total_val_count.html?itemid=5555**

with content

```
total.val={"number":1234,"Validation":YES}
```

i want output like this **itemid:number** using awk

```
5555:1234
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that '?' sign is part of your filenames, since it is special to `bash` shell, or is it excerpt from apache log or something with calls to CGI bin executables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have GNU Awk:

```
$ gawk '
  BEGINFILE{
    split(FILENAME,a,/=/)
  } 
  match($0,/"number":[0-9]+/){
    printf "%s:%d\n", a[2], substr($0,9+RSTART,RLENGTH)
  }
  ' total_val*
5555:1234
```

Or with Perl

```
$ perl -lnE '$x = (split /=/,$ARGV)[1]; say "$x:$1" if /"number":(\d+)/' total_val*
5555:1234
```

In neither case is any checking done (for example, that the filename splits successfully on an `=` sign).